# Export products from VirtueMart 1.12(Joomla 1.0) to VM 1.17(Joomla 1.5)

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

I have to export products from Virtue Mart 1.12 wich run an old Joomla 1.0 based site.
The new site has Joomla 1.5 and Virtue Mart 1.17.
My problem is that CSV improved not support Joomla 1.0, so I don't know how can I get the data?

I heard an another solution: replace the sql tables of virtue mart with the old unit.
I have 2 query about this:

- it can be problem that there is a big version difference between VMs?
- I don't know how can I export just selected tables in PhpMyAdmin?

Big thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have an old copy of VM in J1.0, but you should be able to do this with phpMyAdmin. First thing you will need to do is go in to the old site and find the pertinent VM tables. Most likely jos_vm_category, jos_vm_product, vm_product_category_xref, and jos_vm_product_price at a minimum (these are 1.1.7, J1.5 tables). Then compare the fields in each table. You can export or import entire tables using the export and import tabs in phpMyAdmin. Use CSV files so you can open them in Excel and manipulate them. When you import, you will need to remove any columns you are not going to import from the CSV, then make a list of field names that correspond with the columns you are importing so that the values go in the right place.